# Use of secondary indexes in a redis database in comparison with SQL statements

Tags: python, sql, database, redis, nosql

I'm working with a redis database. I have already implemented Python code to access the redis server. The problem is that the code implemented is complex and not easy maintainable.

### Secondary indexes in Redis database

To simplify the question I suppose that in my database are present a set of 4 keys inserted by the following commands:

```
hset key:1 id 1 field1 1001
hset key:2 id 2 field1 999
hset key:3 id 3 field1 1002
hset key:4 id 4 field1 1000
```

Previous set of keys is ordered by the field `id`. I have used the [Secondary indexing guide](https://redis.io/docs/manual/patterns/indexes/) of the Redis documentation to implement a secondary index to get the keys list ordered by `field1`.
To do this, according with the [guide](https://redis.io/docs/manual/patterns/indexes/), I have created a **sorted set** called `zfield1` inside the database by the following commands:

```
zadd zfield1 1001 1
zadd zfield1 999 2
zadd zfield1 1002 3
zadd zfield1 1000 4
```

The sorted set `zfield1` is ordered by the field `field1` of the keys `key:1`, `key:2`, `key:3`, `key:4` ==> `field1` has been used as **score** for the sorted set `zfield1`.

With the command `zrange` I get the list of `id` field ordered by `field1`:

```
zrange zfield1 0 -1
1) "2"
2) "4"
3) "1"
4) "3"
```

The first element of the list obtained by `zrange` is `"2"` and this element provides the information to get all the value of the key with the lower `field1` value. So by the following command I can get all key values relatives to `key:2`:

```
hgetall key:2
1) "id"
2) "2"
3) "field1"
4) "999"
```

With a suited loop that executes the command `hgetall`, I can get all the key values ordered by `field1`.

### Compare with a SQL database

I think that the previous presentation is the implementation of the following SQL query (where `TABLE1` is a table in a generic SQL database):

```
SELECT * from TABLE1 order by field1
```

This is the first time that I use Redis and if I compare it to the SQL query I think that its usage it is more complex respect of a SQL database.
So I have the doubt that there are other more simple ways to implement a SQL query as `SELECT * from TABLE1 order by field1` with Redis.

### Question

Someone could tell if there are other Redis commands (for example a particular use of the Redis command `KEYS`) that help to get keys ordered by a secondary index?

**Note:** Useful links on this topic are also welcome.

Comment: Did you check the RediSearch module for Redis (part of Redis-Stack)?

Comment: I have found it in my search of solutions, but I didn't use it. Do you think it can help to do query (sometimes complex) in a more easy way?

Comment: For sure, RediSearch is giving you very extensive query API. 
See: https://redis.io/commands/ft.search/ 
https://redis.io/commands/ft.aggregate/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is the first time that I use Redis and if I compare it to the SQL query I think that its usage it is more complex respect of a SQL database

Indeed: Redis' main goal is performance and its data structures and commands are designed with that in mind. There are no *native* secondary indexes in Redis, as keeping one would have a non-negligible cost: in fact, [the guide you referenced](https://redis.io/docs/manual/patterns/indexes/) shows a pattern you can use to *mimic* one, as the data type used there is just a sorted set - which is a first citizen in the Redis ecosystem. A relational database is a completely different beast.

If you wish to use multiple *indexes* in Redis then I would suggest creating and maintaining multiple keys (using the aforementioned sorted set data type would be okay) while you create/modify/delete your main keys.

Comment: Thanks your answer tells me that I think I am in the right way in my use of Redis, in fact when I create/modify/remove keys I maintain multiple sorted sets. If I refer to my question I need to do queries that select keys by a datetime interval and the keys selected must be returned ordered by an other index that in the example is `field1`. This means that I have created 2 sorted keys and a lot of lines of code to get the result. Sometimes I think that this is not the right tool but at this point I have to continue. Thank you and if you can add some other tips.

Comment: You are welcome. I believe Redis is an awesome tool: whether to consider it the right product or not really depends on your business needs. If you can afford leaving the comfort zone of SQL to embrace a different model and data types with the goal of improving the speed of your system then yes, Redis may really be the right tool. But 
I believe relational databases are a great solution as well. Maybe you could consider using both SQL and NOSQL in your app, to get the most out of the two categories.